# DpHostW.`.exe` process doesn't respond and use 25% CPU?

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, sleep, process, cpu-usage

Sometimes when my Dell Vostro 3300 have been in sleep mode and then wake up, the fingerprint reader doesn't work. I also notice the cooling fan runs high and the process "**DpHostW.exe**" that is used for the biometric hardware **use 25% CPU**.

I kill the process and the CPU load goes down to normal levels again.

I haven't found any updates whatsoever on Dell's support pages or Digital Personas support pages (the vendor behind the process). Maybe it's just bad written software that can't handle the sleep mode?

I use Windows 7, 64-bit with latest updates.

Any ideas or similar experience?

(Any suggestions like "re-install" the software, Windows etc are not of interest, thanks)

Comment: I suspect your computer is quad-core? The process running at 25% simply means this process is maxing out one of the cores.

Comment: Dunno if you solved the problem, but I've got the same exact experience. I'm running a Vostro 3700 with an Core i7 processor, Windows 7 64bit, polish lang. After a couple sleep/wakup cycles + hibernate, the service utilizes one of the 8 cores (quadcore with HT enabled). Haven't found any other workaround then you... find it, kill it ;)

Comment: I may experience some improvement since 1-2 months back (or less problems) after the SP1 for Win7 and also the latest update from Digital Personas. If I'm not mistaken I both got an update through Windows Update (optional, need to be manually ticked) and I also ran the built-in software update in the Digital Personas software a couple of times. Good luck!